# Telemetry data unable to pass through root rule chain with node save timeseries

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, thingsboard

Things Board Version: V3.4.1 CE
OS: Window
Database: postgreSQL timescale
Queue: Rabbitmq

I discover that the telemetry data unable to pass through things board root rule chain with the node of the name save timeseries, i am not sure what is happening, i confirm there should be no problem on the connection between thingsboard and also postgreSQL...

I can see debug from here to know the problem is because failed to save to timeseries data....
[image]

```
2022-11-02 09:04:27,148 [sql-queue-2-ts timescale-11-thread-1] ERROR o.t.s.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue - [TS Timescale] Failed to save 2 entities
```

org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to rollback against JDBC Connection
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:593)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:835)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:809)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:672)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sqlts.insert.timescale.TimescaleInsertTsRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$693764a7.saveOrUpdate()
at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sqlts.timescale.TimescaleTimeseriesDao.lambda$init$1(TimescaleTimeseriesDao.java:89)
at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue.lambda$init$2(TbSqlBlockingQueue.java:74)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to rollback against JDBC Connection
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:127)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:304)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:142)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:589)
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:515)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.rollback(Unknown Source)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:396)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:121)
... 19 common frames omitted
2022-11-02 09:04:27,148 [tb-rule-engine-consumer-37-thread-35 | QK(Main,TB_RULE_ENGINE,system)-10] INFO  o.t.s.s.q.DefaultTbRuleEngineConsumerService - Failed to process [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMkaa.png) messages
2022-11-02 09:04:27,148 [tb-rule-engine-consumer-37-thread-35 | QK(Main,TB_RULE_ENGINE,system)-10] INFO  o.t.s.s.q.DefaultTbRuleEngineConsumerService - [c1737420-58eb-11eb-808a-dfdc947dc52b] Failed to process message: TbMsg(queueName=Main, id=1318aa98-0755-49b0-9685-a71a2326ff7d, ts=1667351067141, type=POST_TELEMETRY_REQUEST, originator=354d8300-aa84-11ec-9a47-4727b3504d5d, customerId=d7094170-5c4c-11eb-b06a-c93fc5e45132, metaData=TbMsgMetaData(data={deviceType=Sensor, deviceName=RMS Voltage Sensor, ts=1667351067141}), dataType=JSON, data={"timestamp":1667351069011,"values":[{"id":"CnB Prai Gateway.RMS Shearline.Sensor5_Active","v":true,"t":1667291491472},{"id":"CnB Prai Gateway.RMS Shearline.Sensor5_Battery","v":296,"t":1667342191745},{"id":"CnB Prai Gateway.RMS Shearline.Sensor5_Signal","v":65478,"t":1667350910940},{"id":"CnB Prai Gateway.RMS Shearline.Sensor5_Voltage","v":0,"t":1667351068948}]}, ruleChainId=c1c082b0-58eb-11eb-808a-dfdc947dc52b, ruleNodeId=null, ctx=org.thingsboard.server.common.msg.TbMsgProcessingCtx@4c99aecc, callback=org.thingsboard.server.common.msg.queue.TbMsgCallback$1@415dca17), Last Rule Node: [RuleChain: Root Rule Chain|RuleNode: Save raw telemetry(71b87e70-177d-11ec-9530-3197ec48e7c5)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use generator node to test where the problem is.

First you should test if you can save basic message (like the one you get when you open generator node). With this you will confirm that you can save data to database.

After that you should configure generator node to act as your device, and have same data and metadata as you would get from you device/integration.

Reach out back here with your findings from that.

Generator rule node ref: https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/action-nodes/#generator-node